# How can I configure a springboot java application to send traces to jaeger

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, open-telemetry, jaeger

I have a springboot application deployed in my kubernetes cluster. I would like to start collecting traces and send them to my jaeger (deployed with jaeger operator).

I tried to follow a couple of documentations and articles regarding that, but couldn't find any that address the flow in kubernetes (most of them use docker-compose). Also, I want to use the open telemetry SDKs, since it seems like the jaeger client is deprecated.

My jaeger operator and crd are deployed in observability namespace in cluster.

I tried to follow this setup for example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-opentelemetry-setup.

I am not sure what should be configured in the spring.sleuth.otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint or exporter.jaeger.endpoint.

Also not sure whether sidecar.jaegertracing.io/inject: "true" annotation in my java application deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer about the correct property, but I can give some advice:

- The article you're referring to is about an older version of Spring Boot. Spring Boot 3 uses micrometer tracing, which also supports OpenTelemetry/OTLP as described [here](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3).
- I have created a [spring starter](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-opentelemetry-starter/) myself that tries to make it as easy as possible to use OpenTelemetry. It has "Grafana" in the name, but it can send data to any OTLP endpoint. It also targets Spring Boot 3.
- You can also use the [OpenTelemetry javaagent](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation), which covers older Spring Boot versions as well as other frameworks and is probably the most mature choice at the time of writing.